# Yii2 gridview: render summary if the search returned no results

Tags: gridview, yii2

In yii2 in gridview is a search result count (named `summary`):

Set in gridview:

```
'summary' => "Showing {begin} - {end} of {totalCount} items"
```

Displayed above the table (for example):

```
Showing `1-2` of `2` items.
```

But when the search does not give any results, then the `summary` is not displayed. And I need to display (if empty search):

```
Showing `0-2` of `2` items.
```

I can not find in the settings how to display it (if empty search). Help please.

Comment: Summary would always be like ``Showing 0 of 0 items.`` in this case - why would you want something like this?

Comment: as @rob006 said it won't show the count as you are intending it to display as the `totalCount` belongs to the total number of results found against the search term, and your logic of `Showing 0-2 of 2 items.` on no results will confuse the user it should be `Showing 0 of 2 items` instead, and you can use the `emptyText` property to show it inside the gridview body section, but not at the place where it displays the summary, you can get the total count of the items in the table to achieve it. or maybe you can extend the `yii\grid\GridView` and modify it according to your needs.